# Print the content of ResultIterable object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I print the content of a pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object that has a list of rows and columns

Is there a built-in function for that?

I would like something like `dataframe.show()`

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Is there any chance you accept my answer bellow? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and solved it eventually, so let me share my way of doing it...

Let us assume we have two RDDs.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')])
```

Let us cogroup those RDDs in order to get ResultIterable.

```
cogrouped = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)
for t in cogrouped.collect():
    print t

>>
(1, (<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107c49450>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107c95690>))
(2, (<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107c95710>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107c95790>))
(3, (<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107c957d0>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x107c95810>))
```

Now we want to see what is inside of those ResultIterables.
We can do it like this:

```
def iterate(iterable):
    r = []
    for v1_iterable in iterable:
        for v2 in v1_iterable:
            r.append(v2)

    return tuple(r)

x = cogrouped.mapValues(iterate)
for e in x.collect():
    print e
```

or like this

```
def iterate2(iterable):
    r = []
    for x in iterable.__iter__():
        for y in x.__iter__():
            r.append(y)
    return tuple(r)

y = cogrouped.mapValues(iterate2)
for e in y.collect():
    print e
```

In both cases we will get the same result:

```
(1, ('A', 'a'))
(2, ('B', 'b'))
(3, ('C', 'c'))
```

Hopefully, this will help somebody in future.